# Curve deformation

Tags: animation, path

I'm trying to animate a car make it follows a curve but as you can see in the photos the car starts to have a lot of deformation. Someone can help me?![enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Comment: We can't see much from the size of the image you've provided. Please use Blender's built-in Window > Save Screenshot menu to create your image then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/313955/edit) your question and add the image into it. It would also help to share your Blend file.  If it's not larger than 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: @JohnEason The image is 1920 × 1080, the size is no problem for me... only problem is without seeing any settings of the curve or scale or how exactly everything is set up in the scene it is hard to tell, since a _Follow Path_ constraint can sometimes be tricky to use.

Comment: Hmm... Usually you can just click on the image and it will be shown fullsized (using Firefox) but not in this case for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably scaled your curve, apply its scale in *Object* mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>